# c#, обработчик в другом классе

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Доброго времени суток.

У меня имеется окно, в котором реализован UserControl

```
<local:iWeekControl/>
```

В данном контроле имеется элемент, у которого нужно задать обработчик двойного нажатия мышью.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DoubleClickHandler"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

  // ...

</ListBox>
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы обработчик DoubleClickHandler был в окне, в котором находится данный UserControl.

Каким образом можно такое реализовать?

Спасибо.

Comment: 1 попробовать переделать на команды. они биндятся на текущий DataContext (взять какую нибудь реализацию EventToCommand ) 2 повесить обработчик на юзерконтрол в целевом окне и уже там ловить и фильтровать соурс евента, но это грязно

Answer (score 1):

Возможно получится использовать InputBindings. Даю пример из кода под рукой

```
<StackPanel.InputBindings>
   <MouseBinding
    Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectGroupCommand,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,  AncestorType=UserControl}}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
    Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" />
</StackPanel.InputBindings>
```